# Is the use of global mutable data acceptable for interrupts in Rust?

Tags: rust, embedded, global, interrupt

I'd like to develop an embedded system where physical button presses trigger interrupts. I need to expose this data externally; however to my best understand, interrupts do not generate a return nor do they take parameters as they can be called anywhere.

Therefore, I'd like to set a global mutable variable when an interrupt is trigger so that the button presses may be detected at a later time. I realize that a global mutable variable is almost always avoidable, though I wonder if this specific instance is considered acceptable.

This question is within the scope of Rust, which I'd like to develop for.

Comment: well if you can't control it yes you are force to use global state

Comment: @Stargateur so would I be correct in saying you must use global mutable data for interrupts?

Comment: The data still doesn't need to be "global" in the sense of a C global extern variable accessible to just anyone. The actual variable can be completely private to the module that sets up the interrupt, and accessed by a well-defined API that hides the manner in which it is handled by the actual interrupt routine.

Comment: @user4815162342 you know you can do that in C too ? even if it's scoped that still a global mutate state to the module.

Comment: @Stargateur I know, and that's why I mentioned "extern variables". Despite C supporting static globals, many people coming from a C background equate global variables with free-for-all writable globals, which should almost always be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

So first I should recommend that you use [RTIC](https://rtic.rs/0.5/book/en/).
It really simplifies using interrupts. It has become many a Rust developers go-to library when dealing with interrupts.

There is also another library called [cmim](https://crates.io/crates/cmim) created by James Munns.
This is actually a nice alternative to use if you don't want to use RTIC.
It's also nicer to use than the `static mut` variable route.

If you want to go the static mutable variable route you'll have to do the *mutex dance*:

```
static GPIO: Mutex<RefCell<Option<GPIOC>>> =
    Mutex::new( RefCell::new( None ) );

#[interrupt]
unsafe fn EXTI4( ) {
    free( | cs | { 
        if let Some( ref mut gpio ) = GPIO.borrow( cs ).borrow_mut( ).deref_mut( ) {
            // Do something useful with gpio...
        }
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a mutable global of some kind would be needed, but there are rust-safe ways of doing so.  Some of the embedded rust libraries have a function that borrows a global as mutable for a limited duration, which is the main way of manipulating low level registers